# iterating a loop macro

Tags: macros, loops

I tried to make a command which give depending on an optional parameter x, x-many `'` signs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{i}%
\newcommand{\commu}[2][]{%
    \setcounter{i}{1}%
    \newtoks\striche%
    \striche={'}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{
        \loop%
                \ifnum\value{i}<#1%
                    \striche=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\striche '}%
                    \stepcounter{i}%
        \repeat%
    }%
    {#2}\the\striche
    }
\begin{document}
    $\commu{\commu[2]{C}}$
\end{document}
```

I expect `${{C}''}'$` but it seems that the outer `\commu` will be ignored because I only get `${C}''$`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can please always show us a minimal but working example instead of a code snippet only? BTW: You should use `\newtoks` not inside a macro that is used several times, because it will allocate a new toks register every time. You should move register allocations outside the macro.

Comment: that is pretty much a minimal example. I think `\newtoks` is the problem but how can I solve this?

Comment: ... a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) is  compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how `\commu[3]{C}` is preferable to `C'''`

Comment: Maybe I want to change the symbol later. And then I will be very glad that I made a macro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\newtoks` should be outside of your macro. Also, you don't need to treat 1 specially using `\ifthenelse` -- just set a default value for #1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{i}%
\newtoks\striche%
\newcommand{\commu}[2][1]{%
    \setcounter{i}{1}%
    \striche={'}%
        \loop%
                \ifnum\value{i}<#1%
                \striche=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\striche'}%
                    \stepcounter{i}%
        \repeat%
     {#2}\the\striche%
    }

    $\commu{\commu[2]{C}}$

    $\commu[2]{C}$

     $\commu{C}$
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: The main difference which makes it work is the location of `\newtoks`. Am I right?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Yes, by having `\newtoks` inside the loop you recreate the token register each time `\comu` executes.

Answer (score 3):

As already told in my comment, you should move the `\newtoks` outside the macro definition. An if you already use `ifthen` package you can use `\whiledo` instead of low-level TeX `\loop…\repeat`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{i}%
\newtoks\striche%
\newcommand{\commu}[2][1]{%
  \setcounter{i}{1}%
  \striche={'}%
  \whiledo{\not\equal{#1}{\value{i}}}{%
    \striche=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\striche'}%
    \stepcounter{i}%
  }%
  {#2}\the\striche
}
\begin{document}
  $\commu{\commu[2]{C}}$

  $\commu{C}$

  $\commu[3]{C}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\C[1]{C\foreach \ii in {1,...,#1}{{}'}}
\begin{document} 
$\C{1}$ $\C{3}$ $\C{8}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Slightly better to have `\newcommand\C[2]{#1\foreach \ii in {1,...,#2}{{}'}}` ?

Comment: This adds unwanted spaces. Try and compare the outputs of `$\C[3]$` and `$C'''$`.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for the accidental comments with random characters. You're right, I'n not noticed this. If this is a problem, first thought for me is simply adjust spaces as needed, some like  `\newcommand\C[1]{C\foreach \ii in {1,...,#1}{{}'\kern-.1ex}\kern.1ex}` seem to work reasonably  I'm waiting for a second thought to come, however ...